# How to send dropdown in front of buttons?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, sweetalert2, vanillajs-datepicker

I have the following [html](https://jsfiddle.net/rando1234/3ongmwy2/3/) with a `SweetAlert2` date picker popup for the `Click me!` button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanillajs-datepicker@1.2.0/dist/css/datepicker-bs5.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/notie/dist/notie.min.css">
    <style>
        .my-footer {
            background-color: #163b65;
            color: #ffffff;
            margin-top: 1.5em;
            height: 5em;
            padding: 1em;
            font-size: 80%;
        }
        .room-image {
            max-width: 50%;
        }
        .redText {
            color: red;
        }
        .notie-container {
      box-shadow: none;
    }
        .swal2-confirm {
      z-index: -1;
    }
        .swal2-deny {
      z-index: -1;
    }
    .date-picker-modal {
        z-index: 10000;
    }
    </style>

    <!-- Other things -->
    <title>My nice page</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <!-- <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a> -->
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <!-- <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a> -->
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Rooms
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/rooms/generals-quarters">General's Quarters</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/rooms/colonels-suite">Colonel's Suite</a></li> -->
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="generals.html">General's Quarters</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="colonels.html">Colonel's Suite</a></li>
                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                            <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/rooms/paupers-shack">Pauper's Shack</a></li> -->
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="paupers.html">Pauper's Shack</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <!-- <a class="nav-link" href="/make-reservation">Make Reservation</a> -->
                        <a class="nav-link" href="reservation.html">Make Reservation</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <!-- <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a> -->
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1 class="mt-5">Search for Availability</h1>
            </div>
        </div>        

        <!-- Second date picker -->
        <form action="reservation.html" method="get" class="needs-validation" novalidate id="date-picker">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="start-date" class="form-label">Starting Date</label>
                        <input required autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" name="start-date" id="start-date" aria-describedby="start-date-help">
                        <small id="start-date-help" class="form-text text-muted">Enter your starting date</small>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="end-date" class="form-label">Ending Date</label>
                        <input required autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" name="end-date" id="end-date" aria-describedby="end-date-help">
                        <small id="end-date-help" class="form-text text-muted">Enter your ending date</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search Availability</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        

        <!-- Other -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <p id="myParagraph">
                    This is some text
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button id="colorButton" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
                            Click me!
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="row my-footer">
        <div class="col">
            Left
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Middle
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Right
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap bundle JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanillajs-datepicker@1.2.0/dist/js/datepicker-full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/notie"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>


    <script>
        let attention = Prompt();
        document.getElementById("colorButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
            let html = `
            <form action="" method="get" class="needs-validation" novalidate id="date-picker-modal">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <input disabled required autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" name="start-date" id="start-date-modal" aria-describedby="start-date-help" placeholder="Start">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <input disabled required autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" name="end-date" id="end-date-modal" aria-describedby="end-date-help" placeholder="End">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            `;
            attention.custom({msg: html, title: 'Choose your dates', width: 400});
        });

        // Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
        (function() {
            'use strict';
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
                // Loop over them and prevent submission
                var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
                    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        }
                        form.classList.add('was-validated');
                    }, false);
                });
            }, false);
        })();

        // vanilla JS date picker
        const elem = document.getElementById('date-picker');
        const rangepicker = new DateRangePicker(elem, {
            // ...options
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        });

        // notie alert
        function notify(msg, msg_type){
            notie.alert({
                type:       msg_type,
                text:       msg,
                stay:       false,
                time:       3,
                position: 'top'
            });
        };

        function notifyModal(title, text, icon, confirmButtonText){
            Swal.fire({
                title: title,
                text: text,
                icon: icon,
                confirmButtonText: confirmButtonText
            });
        };

        // Prompt
        function Prompt(){
            let toast = function(c){
                const {
                    msg = '',
                    icon = 'success',
                    position = 'top-end',
                } = c;
                const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                    toast: true,
                    title: msg,
                    position: position,
                    icon: icon,
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 3000,
                    timerProgressBar: true,
                    didOpen: (toast) => {
                        toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
                        toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
                    }
                });

                Toast.fire({});
            };

            let success = function(c){
                const {
                    msg = '',
                    title = '',
                    footer = '',
                } = c;
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: title,
                    text: msg,
                    footer: footer
                })
            };

            let error = function(c){
                const {
                    msg = '',
                    title = '',
                    footer = '',
                } = c;
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: title,
                    text: msg,
                    footer: footer
                })
            };

            let custom = async function(c){
                const {
                    title = '',
                    msg = '',                   
                    width = '',
                } = c;

                const { value: formValues } = await Swal.fire({
                    title: title,
                    html: msg,
                    width: width,
                    backdrop: false,
                    focusConfirm: false,
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    scrollbarPadding: false,
                    willOpen: () => {
                        const elem = document.getElementById('date-picker-modal');
                        const rangepicker = new DateRangePicker(elem, {
                            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                            showOnFocus: true, 
                        });
                    },
                    preConfirm: () => {
                        return [
                            document.getElementById('start-date-modal').value,
                            document.getElementById('end-date-modal').value
                        ]
                    },
                    didOpen: () => {
                        document.getElementById('start-date-modal').removeAttribute('disabled'),
                        document.getElementById('end-date-modal').removeAttribute('disabled'),
                        document.getElementById('date-picker-modal').style.overflow = "hidden"
                    }
                });

                if (formValues) {
                    Swal.fire(JSON.stringify(formValues))
                };
            };

            return {
                toast: toast,
                success: success,
                error: error,
                custom: custom,
            }
        };
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue is that the `OK` and `Cancel` buttons are obstructing the `vanillajs-datepicker`.  As seen here:

[image: img]

I have tried setting the `z-index` as follows, but it doesn't work.

```
.swal2-confirm {
  z-index: -1;
}
.swal2-deny {
  z-index: -1;
}
.date-picker-modal {
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

What can I do to send the dropdown in front of these buttons?

ADDENDUM

I copy Limon's sample code, and realize that the issue has something to do with `await`.  When that is used, his code also has the date picker obstructed by the button.  Still need further digging.

Answer (score 0):

U can set relative position for element that you want to send to front.
This [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-the-position-property-in-css-to-align-elements-d8f49c403a26/) maybe usefull for you.

Comment: I have tried both the CSS `.date-picker-dropdown { position: relative;}` and the JS `document.getElementsByClassName('date-picker-dropdown').style.position = 'relative'`, and none worked.

Comment: In the browser inspect panel, can you see this? For buttons set static position. Datepicker can be append to bottom of body

Comment: I have set static position for the two buttons, along with very low `z-index`.  The dropdown menu is given very high `z-index` and relative position.  Doesn't work.

Comment: i see your jsfiddle demo, just set z-index: 0 to .swal2-actions

`.swal2-actions {z-index: 0}`

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h70u34jL/1/)

Comment: OK, it works on `JsFiddle`.  However when I copy the `html` code from that demo into an `html` file and open it, it doesn't work.

Comment: How can i help you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252142/discussion-between-catx-and-netlorecomment).

Comment: The problem is completely solved by setting zIndex and position. you just need to find elements that must be changed.

Comment: Yea but I am having issue zeroing down on the right ones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `z-index: 2` on `.swal2-html-container`, I'd recommend this way:

```js
let datepicker

Swal.fire({
  html: `<input id="date" type="text" autocomplete="off">`,
  customClass: {
    popup: 'swal2-with-datepicker',
  },
  // resolve the Swal promise with the datepicker value
  preConfirm: () => {
    return datepicker.getDate()
  },
  // initialize the datepicker after the modal is shown
  didOpen: () => {
    datepicker = new Datepicker(Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#date'))
  },
}).then((result) => {
  console.log(result.value)
})
```

```css
/* put the content of .swal2-html-container above buttons */
.swal2-with-datepicker .swal2-html-container {
   z-index: 2;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanillajs-datepicker@1.3.1/dist/css/datepicker.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanillajs-datepicker@1.3.1/dist/js/datepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also, this example might be useful: https://sweetalert2.github.io/recipe-gallery/input-datepicker.html

Comment: There's something to do with `await` in my code that throws things off.  Any further insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the following is required to fix the issue:

```
.swal2-actions {
    z-index: 0! important;
}
```

The hard part is tracking down this elusive `swal2-actions` element, figuring out that its z-index being overwritten, and preventing that from happening.
The outcome can be seen below.  `await` is needed to acquire the user input, and it's not going away.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanillajs-datepicker@1.2.0/dist/css/datepicker-bs5.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/notie/dist/notie.min.css">
    <style>
        .my-footer {
            background-color: #163b65;
            color: #ffffff;
            margin-top: 1.5em;
            height: 5em;
            padding: 1em;
            font-size: 80%;
        }
        .room-image {
            max-width: 50%;
        }
        .redText {
            color: red;
        }
        .notie-container {
            box-shadow: none;
        }
        .swal2-actions {
            z-index: 0! important;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Other things -->
    <title>My nice page</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <!-- <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a> -->
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <!-- <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a> -->
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Rooms
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/rooms/generals-quarters">General's Quarters</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/rooms/colonels-suite">Colonel's Suite</a></li> -->
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="generals.html">General's Quarters</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="colonels.html">Colonel's Suite</a></li>
                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                            <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/rooms/paupers-shack">Pauper's Shack</a></li> -->
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="paupers.html">Pauper's Shack</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <!-- <a class="nav-link" href="/make-reservation">Make Reservation</a> -->
                        <a class="nav-link" href="reservation.html">Make Reservation</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <!-- <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a> -->
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1 class="mt-5">Search for Availability</h1>
            </div>
        </div>        

        <!-- Second date picker -->
        <form action="reservation.html" method="get" class="needs-validation" novalidate id="date-picker">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="start-date" class="form-label">Starting Date</label>
                        <input required autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" name="start-date" id="start-date" aria-describedby="start-date-help">
                        <small id="start-date-help" class="form-text text-muted">Enter your starting date</small>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="end-date" class="form-label">Ending Date</label>
                        <input required autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" name="end-date" id="end-date" aria-describedby="end-date-help">
                        <small id="end-date-help" class="form-text text-muted">Enter your ending date</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search Availability</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        

        <!-- Other -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <p id="myParagraph">
                    This is some text
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button id="colorButton" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
                            Click me!
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="row my-footer">
        <div class="col">
            Left
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Middle
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Right
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap bundle JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanillajs-datepicker@1.2.0/dist/js/datepicker-full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/notie"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>


    <script>        
        let attention = Prompt();

        document.getElementById("colorButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
            let html = `
            <form action="" method="get" class="needs-validation" novalidate id="date-picker-modal">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <input disabled required autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" name="start-date" id="start-date-modal" aria-describedby="start-date-help" placeholder="Start">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <input disabled required autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" name="end-date" id="end-date-modal" aria-describedby="end-date-help" placeholder="End">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            `;
            attention.custom({msg: html, title: 'Choose your dates', width: 400});
        });

        // Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
        (function() {
            'use strict';
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
                // Loop over them and prevent submission
                var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
                    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        }
                        form.classList.add('was-validated');
                    }, false);
                });
            }, false);
        })();

        // vanilla JS date picker
        const elem = document.getElementById('date-picker');
        const rangepicker = new DateRangePicker(elem, {
            // ...options
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        });

        function notify(msg, msg_type){
            notie.alert({
                type:       msg_type,
                text:       msg,
                stay:       false,
                time:       3,
                position: 'top'
            });
        };

        function notifyModal(title, text, icon, confirmButtonText){
            Swal.fire({
                title: title,
                text: text,
                icon: icon,
                confirmButtonText: confirmButtonText
            });
        };

        // Prompt
        function Prompt(){
            let toast = function(c){
                const {
                    msg = '',
                    icon = 'success',
                    position = 'top-end',
                } = c;
                const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                    toast: true,
                    title: msg,
                    position: position,
                    icon: icon,
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 3000,
                    timerProgressBar: true,
                    didOpen: (toast) => {
                        toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
                        toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
                    }
                });

                Toast.fire({});
            };

            let success = function(c){
                const {
                    msg = '',
                    title = '',
                    footer = '',
                } = c;
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: title,
                    text: msg,
                    footer: footer
                })
            };

            let error = function(c){
                const {
                    msg = '',
                    title = '',
                    footer = '',
                } = c;
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: title,
                    text: msg,
                    footer: footer
                })
            };

            let custom = async function(c){
                const {
                    title = '',
                    msg = '',
                    width = '',
                } = c;

                const { value: formValues } = await Swal.fire({
                    title: title,
                    html: msg,
                    width: width,
                    backdrop: false,
                    focusConfirm: false,
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    scrollbarPadding: false,
                    willOpen: () => {
                        const elem = document.getElementById('date-picker-modal');
                        const rangepicker = new DateRangePicker(elem, {
                            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                            showOnFocus: true, 
                        });
                    },
                    preConfirm: () => {
                        return [
                            document.getElementById('start-date-modal').value,
                            document.getElementById('end-date-modal').value
                        ]
                    },
                    didOpen: () => {
                        document.getElementById('start-date-modal').removeAttribute('disabled'),
                        document.getElementById('end-date-modal').removeAttribute('disabled'),
                        document.getElementById('date-picker-modal').style.overflow = "hidden"
                    }
                });

                if (formValues) {
                    Swal.fire(JSON.stringify(formValues))
                };
            };

            return {
                toast: toast,
                success: success,
                error: error,
                custom: custom,
            }
        };
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```